# Python: How to use PyPDF2 to decrypt and pdfminer to extract text?

Tags: python, pypdf, pdfminer

I am trying to extract text from the first page of a secured pdf file. I don't have the password, but the decrypt function in PyPDF2 seems to work fine. But PyPDF2 missed some texts when extracting (used extractText() function). So I want to use pdfminer instead (couldn't install pdftotext on my windows computer, so had to use pdfminer). Here is the current code:

```
    pdfFileObj = open(fileName, 'rb')
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)

    if pdfReader.isEncrypted:
        pdfReader.decrypt('')

    pageObject = pdfReader.getPage(0)
```

Then I want to use pdfminer to read text in pageObject, but cannot figure out how. Could someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: `pageObject` is a PyPDF2 object, it won't work with PDFMiner. There's no point on using PyPDF2 if you can just use PDFMiner to extract the text of the file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @xilopaint. The problem with PDFMiner is that I could not get decryption to work with PDFMiner, but decrypt function in PyPDF2 works like magic.

Comment: If you can decrypt providing a blank password as your sample shows I guess you might extract the text with PDFMiner providing a blank password as well. If not, you have to write the unencrypted file with PyPDF2 before processing it with PDFMiner.

Comment: Thanks xilopaint! Now I have to figure out how to write the decrypted file with PyPDF2. Thought it could be easy but actually not. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52173955/python-pypdf2-writer-does-not-work-with-decryption)

Answer (score 0):

PyPDF2 has improved it's text extraction a lot in 2022. You should just give it a try again (and move to pypdf - I'm the maintainer of pypdf and PyPDF2).

If you still want to use PyPDF2 for dealing with the decryption and pdfminer to extract, you can do this:

1. Read the PDF with PyPDF2.PdfReader
2. Create a new PDF with PyPDF2.PdfWriter (now it's decrypted)
3. Use pdfminer to read the newly written unencrypted PDF